# How to remove "extra" edges from a multigraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, filtering

I programmatically generate many large undirected graphs. Sometimes these graphs are multigraphs, that is, they contain more than one edge between a pair of nodes. I've tried to delete the "extra" edges, to keep only one per node pair, with no success. It should be trivial, but I can't find a simple solution.

Take for instance, the following simple graph:

```
G0 = Graph[{a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a, b <-> a, b <-> c, b <-> a}, 
VertexLabels -> All]
```

[image]

How to keep only one edge between `a` and `b`, and one edge between `c` and `b`?

I've tried some very inefficient ways, but no success. I'd like to know if there's a simple solution (since the problem seems trivial at glance).

Note: If there are self-loops, I'd still like to keep them, therefore `SimpleGraph[]` is not a solution for this particular problem.

Thank you,

Pedro

Comment: [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html).

Comment: I've found taking my glasses off sometimes does the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Graph[
  DeleteDuplicates[
  Sort /@ {a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a, b <-> a, b <-> c, b <-> a}], 
  VertexLabels -> All]
```

or

```
Graph[
 DeleteDuplicates[
 Map[Sort, {a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a, b <-> a, b <-> c, b <-> a}]],
 VertexLabels -> All]
```

Comment: Wow, this is very simple and works with my large networks, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> ***if self-loops are not needed***

- [**SimpleGraph[g]**](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/SimpleGraph.html)
  removes all self-loops and multiple edges between the same vertices.

So

```
SimpleGraph[G0, Options @ G0]
```

[image]

But ...

> ***in my case, I'd still need them if they exist.***

So it is not as simple any more:

```
simpleGraph = Graph[First /@ Gather[Sort /@ EdgeList @ #], Options @ #] &

G1 = Graph[{a <-> b, a <-> a, a <-> a,a <-> a, b <-> c, c <-> a,
     b <-> a, b <-> c, b <-> a},  VertexLabels -> All, ImageSize -> 200];

Row[{G1, SimpleGraph[G1, Options @ G1], simpleGraph @ G1}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use

```
simpleGraph2 = EdgeDelete[#, Flatten[Rest /@ Gather[Sort /@ EdgeList @ #]]]&;
simpleGraph3 = AdjacencyGraph[VertexList @#, Unitize @ AdjacencyMatrix @ #, Options@#]&;
```

Comment: This is a great option if self-loops are not needed (in my case, I'd still need them if they exist). Thank you! @kglr

Answer (score 6):

As others said, [`SimpleGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SimpleGraph.html) will do this. But it will also remove self-loops.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 1, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}]
```

[image]

```
SimpleGraph[g]
```

[image]

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has functions to deal precisely with this problem.

`IGSimpleGraph` has options which control the removal of self-loops and multi-edges separately. We can just turn off self-loops removal.

```
IGSimpleGraph[g, SelfLoops -> True]
```

[image]

There is also a function that merges multi-edges and combines their weights.  The default combiner adds up the weights—for unweighted graphs this means counting how many edges were merged.

```
IGWeightedSimpleGraph[g, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

[image]

---

A final note:  I know that you are already familiar with IGraph/M.  When there is an issue like this, it is always worth checking if IGraph/M has a solution—it often does, especially when the problem is this common.  IGraph/M development is driven by practical issues that come up during real-world network analysis tasks, not by mere guesses about what users might or might not need.

Comment: that's actually a great solution. I've explored IGraph/M, but most of the time I try to use simple built-in MMA functions. Next time I'll check IGraph before trying to solve something that might be already implemented there. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroSapichu BTW all feedback about IGraph/M (especially constructive criticism) is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is you after

```
SimpleGraph[G0]
```

[image]